# UPDATE/JOIN using date ranges

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

Hello I am trying to do an update/join on two tables based on a few conditions.  Here are the structures of my two tables:

Table 1

```
Pricelist     Product     Price     Effective Date     Expiry Date
1             1           NULL      2012-07-01         2013-06-30
1             2           NULL      2012-07-01         2013-06-30
1             3           NULL      2012-07-01         2013-06-30
```

Table 2

```
Pricelist     Product     Price     As of Date
1             1           50.00     2013-06-26
1             1           55.00     2013-07-02
1             2           77.00     2013-06-26
1             2           108.00    2013-07-02
1             3           250.00    2013-06-29 
1             3           263.00    2013-06-30
1             3           266.00    2013-07-01
```

etc.

As you might imagine, I need the resultant table to look like this:

Table 3

```
Pricelist    Product      Price     Effective Date     Expiry Date
1            1            50.00     2012-07-01         2013-06-30
1            2            77.00     2012-07-01         2013-06-30
1            3            263.00    2012-07-01         2013-06-30
```

The conditions apart from joining on Pricelist and Product, is that the "As of Date" in Table 2 must be the less than or equal to the "Expiry Date" in Table 1.

Here is my code so far:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[Price] = B.[Price]
FROM [Table1] A 
INNER JOIN [Table2] B
ON A.[Pricelist] = B.[Pricelist]
AND A.[Product] = B.[Product]
HAVING MAX(B.[as_of_DATE]) <= A.[Expired Date]
```

And of course this is wrong, I just am unsure of the syntax to get it to work.  Help is much appreciated in advance.  Cheers!

Comment: did u try where instead of having???

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and see if it works for you.

```
UPDATE [Table1]
SET [Table1].[Price] = B.[Price]
FROM (SELECT B.[Product], B.[Pricelist],
        MAX(B.[as_of_DATE]) as Max_Date
     FROM [Table2] B 
     GROUP BY B.[Product], B.[Pricelist]
) AS C
JOIN [Table2] B ON B.[Pricelist] = C.[Pricelist] 
    AND B.[Pricelist] = C.[Pricelist]
    AND B.as_of_DATE = c.Max_Date
WHERE [Table1].[Pricelist] = C.[Pricelist]
    AND [Table1].[Product] = C.[Product]
HAVING C.[Max_Date] <= [Table1].[Expired Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE t1
set t1.price = t2.price_new 
from table1 t1
inner join
(

    select a.*, 
    b.price price_new,
    row_number() over (partition by a.pricelist, a.product 
                       order by as_of_date desc) price_rank
    from table1 a
    inner join table2 b 
    on a.pricelist = b.pricelist and a.product = b.product
    where b.as_of_date between effective_dt and expiry_date
) t2 
on t1.pricelist = t2.pricelist and t1.product = t2.product and t2.price_rank = 1;

select * from table1
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3280/15)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another solution using CTE

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT A.price, B.price NewPrice, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.[Pricelist], A.[Product] ORDER BY B.[as_of_DATE]) rn
  FROM [Table1] A 
  LEFT JOIN [Table2] B
  ON A.[Pricelist] = B.[Pricelist]
    AND A.[Product] = B.[Product]
    AND B.[as_of_DATE] <= A.[expiry_date]
)

UPDATE CTE SET Price = NewPrice  WHERE rn=1;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3280/26)**

P.S. Thanks to @rs. for fiddle.